# 1.0.0-beta in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create a new c# class library in Visual Studio 2015 but when I to compile, the only option is "1.0.0-beta5" as the Framework.

I need this under 4.0.  Why is it doing this?

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.NET vNext? If so, you can only create .NET Core assemblies for that.

Comment: No this is a regular C# class library (DLL) that needs to target 4.o.

Comment: Do you have a `project.json` file?

Comment: I strongly suspect it's not a regular C# class library, but an ASP.NET vNext class library

Comment: I could swear it's not set up that way.  I'm pretty careful with the initial setup.

Comment: You're probably selecting `Class Library (Package)` which is for ASP.NET 5 class libs. There should be a separate `Class Library` project option.

Comment: Yes I have a project.json .. I'll post a follow-up for formatting.

Comment: {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "GetTaxesAndFees Class Library",
  "authors": [ "Patrick" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }
  }
}

Comment: Is there an easy way to migrate this if I have to start all over??

Comment: It's just super-basic classes that 4.0 will understand ... nothing complex in here at all.  In fact it's a "shell" program at this point.

Comment: You can probably pretty easily just copy your files over and add them to the new project.

Comment: No vNext ... I want a standard 4.0 C# class library.

Comment: Alright, that's what we'll do.   Thanks.

Comment: And the fact I got a response from Jon Skeet ... thank you again (everyone!).

Answer (score 2):

> I need this under 4.0. Why is it doing this?

Because you made a class library for ASP.NET vNext.

[image]

> Is there an easy way to migrate this if I have to start all over?

I would just create a new class library, and move all code files there, which you then can include. The `project.json` and old skool `csproj` files aren't compatible, so you have to do the set-up by hand. So don't forget the references and the custom actions you might have.

Comment: This is what I chose originally ... I know for a fact because I'm very careful given the huge number of choices..

Comment: Your note isn't 100% true. If you are only targeting .NET 451 in your asp.net vNext project, you can reference non vnext libraries.

Comment: Also the icon is the Nuget icon, not a vNext icon.

Comment: @DaveZych thanks. Removed the note. OP doesn't seem to be after that at all.

Comment: I'm going to have to do it all over again, selecting what I assume is the same option, and hope VS plays by the rules.

Comment: Thanks, as a software developer for decades I'm used to one mis-click changing the entire game.  I'll get it migrated over.

Comment: Nope, all set, thanks.   I had to remove the whole thing and start from scratch, making sure the (Package) option was not the selected one.

Comment: Glad you could fix it. Please don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You selected `Class Library (Package)` (the red in the image below) which is for ASP.NET 5 projects. You want `Class library` (the yellow):

[image]

You shouldn't need to start completely over - you should be able to create a new `Class Library` project, copy your files over and add them to the project.

Comment: http://imgur.com/RdWLJjt ... that's definitely what I chose.  Which is what I'm so confused.  Been doing this for 20 years.

Comment: Well, the fact you have a `project.json` file shows it used the vNext template, so either way, you should change.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now.  Thanks.